# php regex doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: php, regex

String:

`https://fakedomain.com/2017/07/01/the-string-i-want-to-get/`

Code:

```
$url = 'https://fakedomain.com/2017/07/01/the-string-i-want-to-get/';
$out = [];

preg_match('\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(.*)', $url, $out);

// At this point $out is empty... 

// Also...  I tried this (separately)

$keywords = preg_split("\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(.*)", $url);
// also $keywords is empty...
```

I've tested the regex externally and it works. I want to split out the `/the-string-i-want-to-get/` string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$keywords = preg_split("\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(.*)", $out);` Swap variable?

Comment: So how is it to work on the $url?

Comment: No no. You have to do differently.

Comment: You missed regex delimiters, use `preg_match('\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(.*)', $url, $out);`

Comment: should be preg_match('/\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(.*)/', $url, $out); I'm surprised no warning thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a regex. In this case it's better to use `parse_url` and some other helpers like `trim` and `explode`.

```
<?php    
$url = 'https://fakedomain.com/2017/07/01/the-string-i-want-to-get/';

$parsed = parse_url($url);
$Xploded = explode('/',trim($parsed['path'],'/'));
print $Xploded[count($Xploded)-1];

// outputs: the-string-i-want-to-get
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for that:

```
echo basename($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `preg_split`
>   Split string by a regular expression. Split the given string by a regular expression.

Your `$url` will be split by the dates. That's not the way you need to do:

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://fakedomain.com/2017/07/01/the-string-i-want-to-get/';
  $out = [];
  preg_match('/\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(.*)/', $url, $out); 
  // See here...
  var_dump($out);
```

You will get an array of two elements:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "/2017/07/01/the-string-i-want-to-get/"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "/the-string-i-want-to-get/"
}
```

Comment: It's not even necessary to initiate $out as [] - also surrounding .* in paren not necessary

Comment: @JasonGenX Would you like to improve my answer. I don't understand it fully.